# Error in CreateProcessW: cannot convert parameter 9 from 'STARTUPINFO' to 'LPSTARTUPINFO &'

Tags: c++, windows, createprocess

I understand that `startup_info` is a pointer to a `STARTUPINFO` structure

I have a function which I pass startup_info by reference into it. So we can say that I am passing a pointer by reference

```
void cp(....., LPSTARTUPINFO & startup_info) {
  CreateProcessW(....., startup_info);
}
```

Let us assume that I call function cp in this function caller()

```
void caller() {
  STARTUPINFO startup_info; 
  cp(....., startup_info); // error occurs here, I cannot convert 'STARTUPINFO' to 'LPSTARTUPINFO &'
}
```

It will give me error message: Error in CreateProcessW:  cannot convert parameter 9 from 'STARTUPINFO' to 'LPSTARTUPINFO &'

But since statup_info is a pointer, I should be able to pass this into function cp right?

EDIT:
Thank you for your advices,but the following works for me:
`LPSTARTUPINFO` is a pointer to `STARTUPINFO` structure

So I change to

```
void cp(....., LPSTARTUPINFO startup_info_ptr) {
      CreateProcessW(....., startup_info_ptr); // pass in pointer of startup_info
}

void caller() {
      STARTUPINFO startup_info; 
      cp(....., &startup_info); // passing the address of startup_info
}
```

Comment: please show the complete code, or at least the parts relevant to where the error occurs

Comment: Is `startup_info` a pointer? What makes it so?

Comment: function `caller()` expects LPSTARTUPINFO (a pointer to STARTUPINFO struct), but you're passing it a STARTUPINFO (an object of a struct, which is not a pointer).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two `startup_info`'s. In `caller()`, it's a `STARTUPINFO` (not a pointer). In `cp()`, it's a `STARTUPINFO*&` (reference to a pointer). Why? It's most likely unintentional.

I'd expect:

```
void cp(....., STARTUPINFO* pStartup_info) {
  CreateProcessW(....., pStartup_info);
}
void caller() {
  STARTUPINFO startup_info; 
  cp(....., &startup_info);
}
```

In production code, I avoid `p` prefixes for pointers but I've used it here to disambiguate the two `startup_info`'s which you had.